# Permission to manipulate files in Hudson workspace

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hudson

Hi I am having trouble working with the Hudson workspace. I am using fabric to manipulate source files on the Hudson CI server. By default, the source files are downloaded from subversion server to workspace folder, with "hudson" as the owner.

On the ubuntu machine that runs Hudson CI, I cannot run the "cp" command on a source file even though the OS user belows to admin and adm group and also a sudoer. The error looks like:

> cp: cannot create regular file `b.t':
>   Permission denied

What am I missing? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Check the user that Hudson runs under. Check the destination directory, if the Hudson user really has permission to create a file. You can login as the Hudson user and try to copy the file manually.

If nothing else helps, ask a Linux expert.